# If $x_1$,$x_2$ are two solutions, prove $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} x_1(t)-x_2(t)$ exists

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

We are given $x'''+5x''+6x'=f(t)$, where $f(t)$ is continuous on $(-\infty ,\infty )$. We are asked to prove that if $x_1$,$x_2$ are two solutions, then the $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} x_1(t)-x_2(t)$ exists.

I think $1$,$e^{-2t}$,$e^{-3t}$ are basic roots for the equation, but I don't think the limit exists when $t\rightarrow\infty$. Instead, I only think the limit exists when $t\rightarrow\infty$.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't $\to\infty$ mean $t\to+\infty$ in the contexts of calculus and differential equations? Unless there's a reason you're working in the projective line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ are solutions to the inhomogeuos equation, then   $$ x(t)=x_1(t)-x_2(t)$$ is a solution of the homogeneous  equation $$x'''+5x''+6x'=0$$

The solutions are found to be $$ x(t)=c_1+c_2e^{-2t}+c_3e^{-3t}$$

As you notice, we get $$\lim _{t\to +\infty} (x_1(t)-x_2(t))=c_1$$

Comment: Is t→∞  equivalent with t→+∞ here?

Comment: @yLccc  Yes of course, thanks for your helpful comment.